# Block Allocation in a File System - C Programming

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I have to create a cp/m file system on a simulated disk using block allocations.

**Initialise Disk** create and initialise disk control structures List
   Files in the Directory the directory is initially empty

**Display the Free Bitmap** all blocks, except block 0, are initially free

**Open/Create File** if the file name specified is not in the directory,
   a new file will be created

**Read File** list the blocks occupied by the file (not the content of these blocks)

**Write File** allocate another block to the file, you should not preallocate     blocks for the file, you should allocate the first available block

**Delete File** deallocate all blocks, and free the directory entry

as you can see on my code below, im struggling to understand how to integrate the basic file system functions with the block allocations. Im trying to initialise the disk with the toggle_bit function allocating the structure from the header file. Is this alright?

```
/* cpm.c
   Useful functions for Workshop E 
*/
#include"cpm.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE      4096

void oops(char *, char *);
unsigned char bitmap[12];
struct CPMdirent directory[64];

int toggle_bit(int block) /*directory - initilise disk*/
{

    int elem=block/8;
    int pos=block%8;
    int mask=1<<pos;

    bitmap[elem]^=mask;

    return bitmap[elem]&mask;
}


int block_status(int block)
{
    int elem=block/8;
    int pos=block%8;
    int mask=1<<pos;

    return bitmap[elem]&mask;
}


int main(int argv, char *av[])
{
    int     choice = 0;
    int     input_fd, output_fd, n_chars, status;

    char    buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    char    cwd[1024];
    char    file_name[9];

    FILE    *fptr;

    struct  dirent *dir;
    DIR     *dp;

    do
    {
        printf("Please choose a task (enter the number)\n");
        printf("1. Intialise Disk\n");

        switch(choice)
        {
            /*Intialising the disk (store directory in arrays)*/
            case 1:
                printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~ Initialising the disk ~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
                toggle_bit(0);
                directory[0].usercode;
                directory[0].filename[9];
                directory[0].filetype[4];
                directory[0].extent;
                directory[0].blockcount;
                directory[0].blocks[16];
                printf("\nDisk sucessfully initialised.\n");
                break;

    }
    while(choice != 8);

}

void oops(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s ", s1);
    perror(s2);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: This is `C` code. But you put the code into html snippet.

Comment: yea sorry im kinda new using this site :)

Comment: @Youtrippin do you have any specific problems? Keep in mind you should formulate a clear problem statement (what currently doesn't work, as detailed as possible) and an example desired output (thats already in there). Read [ask] for more info on the matter. Also [mcve]

Comment: pretty much i dont understand the whole block allocation and i need some help to point me in the right direction. But first how do i initialise the disk and check if you have initialised it?

Comment: @Youtrippin Can you formulate a specific problem statement on what you don't understand about it and present the research you've done?

Comment: @Magisch i cant really find a specific problem but its mostly on the CP/M basic functions to allocate blocks to files or using blocks in general as im confused (but i do understand file systems such as stat() write() read() etc.)

Comment: @Magisch i know that the directory has to be in an array, have i correctly intialised it?

Comment: You should have received quite some "code has no effect" warnings on the `directory[0]....` statements. And the compiler would be right, that code doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @tofro so how do i initialise it correctly? with the given structure shown with the usercode, filetype etc.

Comment: @Youtrippin If the question is really "how do i initialize" (which i doubt), the answer is: By assigning useful values to the variables - like `directory[0].blockcount = <useful value>;` If the question is rather "what is a useful value" - Your tags might be wrong. You'll find the useful values in the CP/M file system specifications

Comment: @tofro should i initialise the virtual disk using memset?

Comment: @Youtrippin From your code, I don't see a 'virtual disk'. That should be a large, disk- (or sector- or cluster-) sized block of memory with no structure at all (probably a `malloc`ed block of `uint8_t`). The structures you have defined on top of that can be filled and then `memcpy`ed into the right places, or even modified in-place using pointers. Then write and read sector-sized blocks to the disk file.

Comment: Note a "real" disk driver has a 'layered' structure - On the lowest level, there's `readSector()` and `writeSector()` functions - I'd start implementing those (reading and writing sector-sized blocks into a large disk file). Then think about what needs to go into which sector - Here you can use your defined structures as an overlay. The next layer is typically the "cluster" or "allocation block" layer, and so forth.